# Databases in ASP.net webapplication

Tags: asp.net

How to make the databases machine independent in ASP.net ? When we provide connection string it takes the native machine address . But if we want to make it machine free what should be the procedure ?

Comment: When you say "machine free", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean you want the connection string to be specified within the application, maybe by the end user?

Comment: You could use a Data Source Name (DSN) instead of a machine name or IP address. It's not going to give you much. Some environments prefer this approach, but most I've been in don't since in order to move the code across machines, you need to create/manage the DSNs on the machines hosting the site. (In a multi server environment this could be a lot of work)

Comment: Huh "machine free" part II? `my.db_server_somehere_in_the_world.com`....